# When creating a max heap, where are the elements being stored?

Tags: java, tree, heap

I'm learning about trees and heaps, and for an assignment I created a max heap that I populated with a list of integers.

I can add the numbers just fine, but I don't understand exactly where these numbers are going and how to access them when I do an in-order traversal. I have a linked List and a queue set up, but the numbers I added don't seem to be in either one of them.

Below is the method my teacher gave me to add elements, but when I look at it I don't understand where the added data is going. Where exactly are added elements stored and how would I access them once they've been added?

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;

public class PriorityQueue 
{    
    LinkedList<Node> myList = new LinkedList<>(); 
    Queue<Node> nodes = new LinkedList<>();
    Node num;
    Node root;
    Node head;
    
    private Node addRecursive(Node current, int val)
    {
        //base case 
        if(current == null)
        {
            return new Node(val);       
        }
        if(val > current.value) 
        {
            current.left = addRecursive(current.left, val);
        }
        else if(val < current.value)
        {
            current.right = addRecursive(current.right, val);
        }
        else 
        {
            return current;
        }
        return current;
    }
    
    public void add(int val)
    {
        root = addRecursive(root,val);
    }
```

Comment: The numbers are in node instances, reachable from root.

Comment: The code you have posted never uses `myList` or `nodes`.

Comment: *"I created a max heap"*: the code you have shared creates a *binary search tree*. The title does not match with the code you present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I created max heap

It might be that other code does that, but the code you have shared creates a *binary search tree*.

> Where exactly are added elements stored

Each value is stored in a `Node` instance. Let's see what happens when you execute the following code:

```
PriorityQueue p = new PriorityQueue();
```

The instance `p` has several member variables, but only `root` is relevant for the methods `add` and `addRecursive`. It starts out with the default value `null`. We can picture the structure as follows:

```
  p
  ↓
┌────────────┐   
│ root: null │
└────────────┘
```

Then let's add a value:

```
p.add(5);
```

As `root` is null, the value of the `current` parameter variable is null too. We get in the "base case", and `addRecursive` returns a new node with the given value. The `add` method assigns this returned new node to `root`, so we end up with one node instance that can be accessed via `root`. We can picture it like so:

```
  p
  ↓
┌────────────┐    ┌─────────────┐
│ root: ─────────►│ value: 5    │
└────────────┘    │ left: null  │
                  │ right: null │
                  └─────────────┘
```

Let's add a second value:

```
p.add(2);
```

Now `root` is not null, and the value of the `current` parameter variable is same reference. We find that `val < current.val` (which evaluates to `2 < 5`) is a true expression, so we get into the first `else if` block. There we make a recursive call with:

```
current.right = addRecursive(current.right, val);
```

As `current.right` is null, this recursive call will execute the base case, and when it returns, a new node with value 2 is here assigned to `current.right`. Execution continues to `return current` (which is the root reference) and `add` gets this root reference back and assigns it to `root`. This last assignment doesn't change `root`, as it already had that reference. The essential assignment here, was the one to `current.right`.

We can picture the result like so:

```
  p
  ↓
┌────────────┐    ┌─────────────┐
│ root: ─────────►│ value: 5    │
└────────────┘    │ left: null  │
                  │ right: ───────┐ 
                  └─────────────┘ │
                                  ▼
                               ┌─────────────┐
                               │ value: 2    │
                               │ left: null  │
                               │ right: null │
                               └─────────────┘
```

I would encourage you, to repeat this step-by-step process on a piece of paper for adding more values.

> how would I access them once they've been added

In the above example with two node instances, you can access the values with these expressions:

```
p.root.value;  // 5
p.root.right.value; // 2
```

> how to access them when I do an in-order traversal

An in-order traversal could collect the nodes in a list, but I would not make that list a member variable of your class. A method could make the traversal and *return* the list to the caller. Whether the caller wants to assign it to a member variable or not is their business...

Here are methods for an in-order traversal:

```
    // Helper function
    private void inOrderRecursive(Node current, LinkedList<Node> list) {
        if (current == null) {
            return;
        }
        inOrderRecursive(current.left, list);
        list.add(current);
        inOrderRecursive(current.right, list);
    }
    
    public LinkedList<Node> inOrder() {
        LinkedList<Node> list = new LinkedList<>();
        inOrderRecursive(root, list);
        return list;
    }
```

You can call it as follows:

```
        for (Node node : p.inOrder()) {
            System.out.print(node.value + " ");
        }
```

For the little binary search tree we created, the above would output:

> 5 2